# Perl REGEX not matching when it should

Tags: regex, perl

So I have 2 variables, one a short string and one a long string that should contain the short string. I have added some prints to the script however the match isn't working - could anyone shed any light on this for me:

```
print OUT "Omni: [$omnihostname]\n";
print OUT "API: $api\n";
print OUT "Match: Y\n" if ($omnihostname =~ /$api/i);
print OUT "Match: N\n" if ($omnihostname !~ /$api/i);
print OUT "-----------------------------------------------------------\n";
```

Here's the output:

```
Omni: [ASW02SLO]
API: deviceDetail@deviceId = 10401381@hostName = ASW02SLO@ipAddress = [other redundant text here]
Match: N
-----------------------------------------------------------
```

Thanks,
Ben

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears to me that you have your terms the wrong way around in the regex, i.e. you wish to determine if the shorter string`$omnihostname` is contained in `$API`, not the other way around.

As such, there's a better solution than regexes:

```
if (index($API, $omnihostname) >= 0);  # Match: Y
```

If case-insensitivity is desired, wrap either or both arguments in `lc(...)` as necessary.

NB: `fc(...)` is preferred for case folding in later versions of Perl.

Comment: Why would `index` be a better solution than a regular expression?

Comment: You're a star, I literally use these every day but had a bit of a brain fart doing variable into variable rather than string into variable - thanks!

Comment: Incidentally I kept the regex, just swapped the values round :)

Comment: @Borodin well, I missed the case sensitivity at first, but in general if you just need a pure substring search then a call to `index` should be more efficient than a regex compile/match - it's exactly what the `index` function was designed for.

Answer (score 0):

This is the way that I would do it:

```
use strict;
use warnings; 

my $ss = 'string'; # your 'key'

my @ls = qw(longstring longstringlong longstri); # an array to search through

foreach(@ls){
    chomp;
    print "Match! $_\n" if /$ss/; 
    print "No match! $_\n" if ! /$ss/;
}
```

---

```
Match! longstring
Match! longstringlong
No match! longstri
```